# Accessing nested field from Queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, backend, rest

so I have 4 models

```
class User(models.Model):
   userID = models.CharField(pk = True)
   ......    

class Producer(models.Model):
   userID = models.OneToOneField('Users.User',on_delete=CASCADE,primary_key=True)
   .....

class Buyer(models.Model):
   userID = models.OneToOneField('Users.User',on_delete=CASCADE,primary_key=True)
   .....

class Inventory(models.Model):
   item_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True,default=uuid.uuid4)
   producerID = models.ForeignKey('Producers.Producer',on_delete=CASCADE)
   .....

class Cart(models.Model):
    userID = models.OneToOneField(Buyer, on_delete = CASCADE,primary_key = True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True) 

class Cart_Item(models.Model):
   cart_item_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True,default= uuid.uuid4)
   item_id = models.ForeignKey('Inventory.Inventory', on_delete= SET_NULL,null=True)
   userID = models.ForeignKey(Cart,on_delete=CASCADE)
   ......
```

I then have a post-only view which processes all cart Items in order to create an order as follows

```
class PlaceOrderView(generics.CreateAPIView):

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         user = request.user
         cart = Cart_Item.objects.select_for_update().filter(userID = user).order_by('item_id__producerID')
         
         order = {'producer':'',
                  'items': []
                 }
         for item in cart:
             if order['producer'] == item.values('item_id.producerID'):
                 order['items'].append(item)
             else:
                 self.placeOrder(order)
                 order['producer'] = item.values('item_id.producerID')
                 order['items'] = []
                 order['items'].append(item)
     
     def placeOrder(self,order):

        with transaction.atomic():
           #Business logic on order.
```

What Im trying to do is to group all cart Items by items owned by specific producers, and then place an order for that group of cart Items. Where I am having trouble is in accessing the nested field "producerID" of cart Item, which needs to be done in order to group all of my cart Items.

My placeOrder method, uses the cartItem object and so they are passed directly in the function. Currently I am serializing cart Items in the for loop just to compare the producerID's but this feels inefficient. I've read django documentation on the topic of fields, but there is not much support for nested fields. Some simple explanation on the topic would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.values() is a queryset method, but since you are iterating the qs and working with each individual item you dont need it. If you have and Item you should be apple to access the fk relation

Have you tried:

```
order['producer'] = item.itemId.producerID
```

Comment: wow, very simple. I swear I tried this first but got a syntax error, I may have been too tired. But thanks! this was exactly what I needed.